# ¿Cómo acceder a una colección anidada a través de otra colección por ObjectId en mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Tengo 3 colecciones distintas, y están anidadas a través de su object id de la siguiente manera:

```
BOLETA
{
    numero_boleta:int,
    numero_producto:ObjectId de producto
}

PRODUCTO
{
    id_producto:int,
    numero_contenedor:ObjectId de contenedor
}

CONTENEDOR
{
    id_contenedor:int
}
```

entonces necesito hacer una consulta con `.find()` para mostrar las boletas cuyos productos se encuentren en el mismo contenedor, o sea que el ObjectId asociado a producto sea el mismo, pero con productos diferentes y boletas diferentes. Lo había intentado utilizando

```
db.getCollection('BOLETA').find({numero_producto:ObjectId('1'),numero_producto:ObjectId('2')})
```

donde ambos objects id corresponden a los distintos productos en el mismo contenedor, pero solo me muestra el último.

Comment: Ya tienes la lista de ID de los productos y quieres mostrar las boletas relacionadas con todos esos productos?

Comment: O lo que quieres es teniendo el ID de un contenedor, mostrar las boletas que pertenecen a todos los productos de ese contenedor?